# Explain how a BIOS/UEFI infection may compromise the security of the Operating System

Tags: malware, operating-systems, bios

Explain how a BIOS/UEFI infection may compromise the security of the Operating System.

Comment: This looks like homework. While technically this is not off-topic the OP shows no own research as one could expect when doing homework. Therefore  I propose to close it as too broad.

Comment: Hello and welcome to security.se. Your question is extremely generic and it has many well documented answer that you can easily find by yourself. I suggest you start by googling things like "BIOS infection" and read through the numerous documents on that subject. If you then have more specific questions, by all means ask them here.

Comment: This is not a homework
But for personal knowledge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compromising the security of the Operating System through infecting the BIOS/UEFI is easier said than done though it really exists and a few samples have been seen in the wild. Taking control of the BIOS/UEFI allows the enemy to manipulate the boot sequence of the computer and end up with running malware or using built-in windows code to transmit C2(Command and Control) communications to the attacker's server and download more malware/modules or do certain actions like copying/sending data, open firewall ports, turn off the firewall, and well practically anything since any enthusiastic attacker like that would definitely aim to get kernel-level privileges or in windows terms, SYSTEM level privileges.

TLDR; Think of it like this: Your computer is a 5 storey building with the following floors:

1. 1st Floor - BIOS/UEFI
2. 2nd Floor - Bootloader
3. 3rd Floor - EFI Partition Program
4. 4th Floor - Operating System
5. 5th Floor - User Applications

I'm sure you agree that destroying the 1st floor technically destroys the whole building already.